# PHP increment using 0.01

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
$p1 = array(
    'x' => 0,
    'y' => 0
);

$p2 = array(
    'x' => 10,
    'y' => 10
);

// Work out distances
$pxd = $p2['x'] - $p1['x'];
$pyd = $p2['y'] - $p1['y'];

// Find out steps
for ($x = $p1['x']; $x < $p2['x']; ++ $x) {
    for ($y = $p1['y']; $y < $p2['y']; ++ $y) {
        $coords['gps'] = array(
           'x' => $x,
           'y' => $y
        );
 echo $coords['gps']['x'] .', '.$coords['gps']['y'] . '</br>';
        }

}
```

The above increments by 1 in all the co-ordinates. I would like to increment by 0.001 rather by 1 for the range 0,0 to 10,10 e.g. 0.001, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, etc...

How do I go about it please as I am stuck

Comment: `++$x` should become `$x += 0.001`, same for `y`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
// Find out steps
for ($x = $p1['x']; $x < $p2['x']; $x += 0.001) {
    for ($y = $p1['y']; $y < $p2['y']; $y += 0.001) {
        $coords['gps'] = array(
           'x' => $x,
           'y' => $y
        );
        echo $coords['gps']['x'] .', '.$coords['gps']['y'] . '</br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks the problem is that after sometime it is incrementing by  more decimal points e.g. 0.022, 9.0010000000005 - I'd like to limit it to 4 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

Change increment step from 1 to 0.001:

```
for ($x = $p1['x']; $x < $p2['x']; $x += 0.001) {
    for ($y = $p1['y']; $y < $p2['y']; $y += 0.001) {
        // do your stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(But it will take pretty long with this interval)

```
<?php

    $p1 = array(
        'x' => 0,
        'y' => 0
    );

    $p2 = array(
        'x' => 10,
        'y' => 10
    );

    $interval = 0.001;


    for ($count = $p1['x']; $count < $p2['x']; $count+= $interval) {
        for ($innerCount = $p1['y']; $innerCount < $p2['y']; $innerCount+= $interval) {
            $coords['gps']['x'] = $count;
            $coords['gps']['y'] = $innerCount;
            echo sprintf("%6.3f", $coords['gps']['x']) . ", " . sprintf("%6.3f", $coords['gps']['y']) . "</br>";
        }

    }

?>
```

Output:

```
0.000, 0.000
0.000, 0.001
0.000, 0.002
0.000, 0.003
0.000, 0.004
0.000, 0.005
0.000, 0.006
0.000, 0.007
0.000, 0.008
0.000, 0.009
0.000, 0.010
//...
```